# What probabilty distribution to use? And how to use it?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on test prep and have the following problem which I just can't wrap my head around:

> A manufacturer knows that, on average, 30% of the widgets it produces
>   require repairs with 1 year after they are sold. Suppose that 10
>   widgets are randomly selected and let the r.v. X  be the number of
>   widgets that require repairs.
>
> Find the number $x$ such that the probability that at least $x$ of
>   them will require repairs is less than 0.5.

I would very much appreciate any insight, because I've been staring at this for 3 hours and I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: X follows binomial distribution with $n=10$ and $p=0.3$. Find $x$ such that $P(X\ge x)<0.5$.